# How to simulate passengers in SUMO Simulator?

Tags: passenger, simulation, public, transport, sumo

I am quite new to the SUMO.

I would like to know if it is possible, like MATSim, to simulate the number of passengers on a bus, the number of passengers at a bus stop, and the number of dropping off and picking up passengers and simulate them in the visualizer tool?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the tour and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, please see here for a general overview: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Public_Transport. All vehicles have a personCapacity, see http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Definition_of_Vehicles,_Vehicle_Types,_and_Routes#Available_vType_Attributes and pedestrians are visualized also when embarking and disembarking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! what about the number of waiting passengers at a stop and visualizing them? Also, do you know any sample covering such features?